# Swift with tableView and sections fatal error: unexpected nil when unwrapping

Tags: ios, uitableview, swift

My problem is the following. I have a grouped `TableView` and it is throwing the error with this code:

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController, UITableViewDataSource {

    let sectionsTableIdentifier = "SectionsTableIdentifier"
    var names: [String: [String]]!
    var keys: [String]!

    @IBOutlet weak var tableView: UITableView!


    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.

        tableView.registerClass(UITableViewCell.self, forCellReuseIdentifier: sectionsTableIdentifier)

        let path = NSBundle.mainBundle().pathForResource("sortednames", ofType: "plist")
        let namesDict = NSDictionary(contentsOfFile: path!)
        let names = namesDict as [String: [String]]
        keys = sorted(namesDict!.allKeys as [String])

    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }

    // MARK: Table view data source methods
    func numberOfSectionsInTableView(tableView: UITableView) -> Int {

        return keys.count
    }

    func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {

        let key = keys[section]
        let nameSection = names[key]!
        return nameSection.count

    }

    func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier(sectionsTableIdentifier, forIndexPath: indexPath) as UITableViewCell
        let key = keys[indexPath.section]
        let nameSection = names[key]! //Error here
        cell.textLabel?.text = nameSection[indexPath.row]

        return cell


    }

    func tableView(tableView: UITableView, titleForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> String? {

        return keys[section]

    }


}
```

The error is this fatal error:

```
unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value.
```

I'm not sure why. The data is being loaded from `sortednames.plist` file, it is in the main bundle.

[image: xcode screen]

It is a simple app, there is in no cell identifier yet, but that should not be a problem, I think. I can see the file and the names being added before the crash in the debugger. Any help?

Comment: I rolled back your edit. You should NOT edit the fix into your question. You can answer your own question if you have solved your problem. (but I came first ;)

Comment: Ha thats why, :) cool thanks

Comment: And I will roll back your edit once more. ;)

Comment: Yea sure I had no time to see the first one :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In `viewDidLoad`, instead of assigning to the instance variable `names`, you have created a local variable `names`.

replace this:

```
let path = NSBundle.mainBundle().pathForResource("sortednames", ofType: "plist")
let namesDict = NSDictionary(contentsOfFile: path!)
let names = namesDict as [String: [String]]
keys = sorted(namesDict!.allKeys as [String])
```

with this:

```
let path = NSBundle.mainBundle().pathForResource("sortednames", ofType: "plist")
let namesDict = NSDictionary(contentsOfFile: path!)
names = namesDict as [String: [String]]
keys = sorted(namesDict!.allKeys as [String])
```